# batch variable set, but goes blank immediately after

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, for-loop

So, I have a piece of batch code:

```
    SET "ACTSESS=%tmp%\activesessions.txt"
    NET USE > %ACTSESS%

    setlocal  EnableDelayedExpansion
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%A IN (%ACTSESS%) DO (
        SET "BB=%%A"
        ECHO %BB%
        IF /I "!BB:~0,2!" EQU "\\"  SET "SESSDEL=%BB%"
        NET USE /delete %SESSDEL% /DELETE
        ECHO.
        ECHO -----------------------------------------
        ECHO   %SESSDEL% Ended Successfully. 
        ECHO -----------------------------------------  )
)
```

`SET BB=%%A`
Set gets subbed for the proper variable on the cmd screen - a string in this case like so: `SET "BB=local"`, 
but immediately after `ECHO %BB%` returns `%BB%` as blank.

Am I doing something wrong here?

**UPDATE** Ok, solution was I forgot to put `!!` instead of `%%`  after delayed expansion in for-loop.

This code is to delete *unmapped* sessions on windows, instead of doing `NET USE \\server\share /DELETE` manually on many machines and shares, thought of running this as a service or task. Im sure theres a better way but havent figured it out yet (something to do with persistence and cached logins), so its a quick workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (and within brackets) you need to access your variables enclosed with **!** instead of **%**

```
SET "ACTSESS=%tmp%\activesessions.txt"
NET USE > %ACTSESS%

setlocal  EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%A IN (%ACTSESS%) DO (
    SET "BB=%%A"
    ECHO !BB!
    IF /I "!BB:~0,2!" EQU "\\"  SET "SESSDEL=!BB!"
    NET USE /delete !SESSDEL! /DELETE
    ECHO.
    ECHO -----------------------------------------
    ECHO   !SESSDEL! Ended Successfully. 
    ECHO -----------------------------------------  )
)
```

Comment: Now all you need is some text explaining why the code you've posted is necessary.

Comment: Wait, wait, it worked, thank you! I'll add the explanation in a bit in case anyone finds this useful.